# Cycles Ward BRDF support

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have a model where its material is defined in Ward BRDF. I know that Blender Cycles does not natively support Ward BRDF, but is there any way I can use the Ward BRDF parameters for rendering my model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the parameters?

Comment: Are Anisotropic BSDF and Ward BRDF not similar/same? Check here for details: https://developer.blender.org/D549. And from paper about Ward BRDF (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/330e/59117d7da6c794750730a15f9a178391b9fe.pdf): *"Similar results for the half direction to out direction transform can be found in [Torrance and Sparrow 1967] and [Ashikhmin and Shirley 2000]."* You have Ashikhmin-Shirley distribution in Anisotropic BSDF available.

Comment: Also: https://imgur.com/hNkr2Bv and http://adaptivesamples.com/2014/06/23/ashikhmin-shirley-distribution/ and even: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40586/what-do-glossy-distribution-models-do

Comment: "WardBSDFNode renamed to AnisotropicBSDFNode; has now two distributions (Ward and Ashikhmin-Shirley)" Hmm.. how do I choose between Ward and Ashikhmin-Shirley...

Comment: Carlo, an example parameter would look like, (diffuse albedo, specular albedo, roughness) = ((0.5,0.5,0.5), (0.1,0.1,0.1), 0.05) for isotropic Ward. You can add another roughness parameter for anisotropic Ward.